# MS Word for Mac - change colour of existing INK annotations in whole doc

Tags: microsoft-word, office-for-mac

In the picture below the tick mark and the "M2" were added using lilac-coloured ink:

[image: ink]

The color is a bit hard to read (on screen or paper) so I want to change ALL the ink in the doc to be a darker colour. I can not find a way to do this & have searched online to no avail.

All I can see is a way to format one piece at a time (with following menu) but I want to do it for all the ink in whole doc.

How to change all existing ink colour?

[image: menu]